# Very simple HTML but my Bootstrap columns are not side by side, they are stacking vertically

Tags: html, multiple-columns

If i make the Lorem ipsum shorter it will bump up into the same row, however it is supposed to be next to the image. I know I am missing something small, but I can't seem to find anything that is helping and starting to feel really frustrated.  The layout is supposed to look like the image of the album on the left (about 1/3 of the page) and the title and paragraph to the right of it. (formatting in regards to padding, spacing, centering, etc not part of the lesson. just the columns and rows in bootstrap. I have tried changing the columns to 9 and 3, or even 6 and 6 but it isn't doing anything. I have resized my screen, etc. The reason it is set to medium was it wanted those settings for med and large so that was what to use. Thanks!

Here is my code:
 I have the Doctype at the top and head properly done but don't know how to put them on here yet. Sorry. Still learning there.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Music Store</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/bootstrap.min.css'/>
```

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "jumbotron">
        <h1>Music Store</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-med-4">
        <img src="img/Album.png" >
    </div>

    <div class="col-med-8">
        <h2>Album Title <br>Artist</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo I believe. Your column classes should be "col-md-4", and "col-md-8" Not "col-med-4" and "col-med-8".

Comment: i KNEW it was something little. Wow.that was actually more simple than i prefer (LOL> Thanks!!!!!!